# Unit testing code which uses Umbraco v4 API

Tags: unit-testing, umbraco

I'm trying to write a suite of integration tests, where I have custom code which uses the Umbraco API. The Umbraco database lives in a SQL Server CE 4.0 database (*.sdf file) and I've managed to get that association working fine.

My problem looks to be dependancies in the Umbraco code. For example, I would like to create a new user for my tests, so I try:

```
var user = User.MakeNew("developer", "developer", "mypassword", "my.email@email.com", adminUserType);
```

Now as you can see, I have pass a user type which is an object. I've tried two separate ways to create the user type, both of which fail due to a null object exception:

```
var adminUserType = UserType.GetUserType(1);
var adminUserType2 = new UserType(1);
```

The problem is that in each case the UserType code calls it's `Cache` method which uses the `HttpRuntime` class, which naturally is null.

My question is this: Can someone suggest a way of writing integration tests against Umbraco code? Will I have to end up using a mocking framework such as TypeMock or JustMock?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some resources that may help:

http://www.aaron-powell.com/unit-testing-with-umbraco

http://stream.umbraco.org/video/726639/aaron-powell-unit-testing